# Why is `specialize` not an invalid tactic within a proof?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In the [software foundations book](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Tactics.html#lab167) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20231105153325/https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Tactics.html#lab167)) the `specialize` tactic was introduced as a way to simplify a hypothesis.

I don't understand,why it's a valid step within a proof.

The provided example adds to my confusion:

```
Theorem specialize_example: forall n,
     (forall m, m*n = 0)
  -> n = 0.
Proof.
  intros n H.
  specialize H with (m := 1).
  simpl in H.
  rewrite add_comm in H.
  simpl in H.
  apply H. Qed.
```

When I replace the Hypothesis `(forall m, m*n = 0) -> n = 0.` with `1*n = 0 -> n = 0.`, I see that we're now successfully proofing `n=0` with that new hypothesis.

I don't understand why this is accepted as a proof for the original theorem `forall n, (forall m, m*n = 0) -> n = 0.`. Aren't we now continuing proofing a new theorem `forall n, 1*n = 0 -> n = 0.`?

How does proofing the new theorem generalize to be a valid proof for the original theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aren't we now continuing proofing a new theorem `forall n, 1*n = 0 -> n = 0`.?

Indeed, that's what you are proving at first. But then you can go back to your original theorem and look at the starting point `(forall m, m*n = 0)` . If this statement is true, then it implies `1*n = 0` which by your new theorem implies `n=0`. This therefore proves the original theorem

`(forall m, m*n = 0) -> 1*n = 0 -> n=0`

(I don't know the language coq, so if the above line is syntactically not correct, it is simply meant in mathematical sense `A=>B=>C`).
Dropping the middle part between the two arrows is the original theorem.

Your new theorem is stronger than the original, because it needs less assumptions for the same conclusion.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's starting to make sense. That's valid coq syntax btw. :)

Comment: ah, nice! good to know  : )

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is `(forall m, m*n = 0)`. This means you may assume in your proof, that for every possible `m`, you have `m*n=0`. If you may assume this for any possible `m`, you may also assume it for a specific `m` like `1`.

Note that if you would leave away the parenthesis:

```
Theorem specialize_example: forall n,
     forall m, m*n = 0
  -> n = 0.
```

the theorem would not hold any more - the obvious counter example is `m=0`. The statement with and without parenthesis is very different. With parenthesis you may choose `m` as you like - without parenthesis your theorem must hold for every possible value of m.

Comment: Just to ensure I understand it correctly: The original theorem with the brackets it reads as "for any natural number n, if we can multiply it with a natural number m, and no matter what m is, the product is zero, then we know that n must be zero" and your modified theorem without brackets reads as "for any natural numbers n and m, if their product is zero it means that n is zero"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And this is the reason why you are free to choose m with `specialize` in the "with parenthesis" variant. If you try to prove the "without parenthesis" variant, you see that you introduce `m`, so you can't choose it, and the premise doesn't have a `forall` you can instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

[I'd rather post this as a comment but I am still too new to SO.]

I am reluctant to reply to the first part of your question not to spoil the exercise: Logical Foundations in particular is a journey and a progression as opposed to a compendium of recipes, and the intellectual component of that exercise, and not spoiling it, I think is crucial.

As for your doubts about the validity of such a transformation, maybe I see what you mean: if we are proving a theorem that is supposed to hold for all n, how is it that we can prove it for just some n?  But now notice that it is not on n that we are specializing above, then if you also think how apply-ing on hypotheses as opposed to goals works...

Comment: Of course I want to be respectful to the material and not ask for any exercise solutions. I am a little confused because (as you can see in the link in the question) my question is about an example, not an exercise. Is there another place in software-foundations where my question is part of an exercise?

Comment: I had it with myself really. :) I had no trouble replying to you in English, but I had written some code that makes explicit what you were asking and then I have dropped it as I thought I was spoiling a basic exercise: because LF in particular is a progression and like that at every step, you have to figure it out, a bit like a Project Euler... I don't think you asked an inappropriate question, nor my comment was motivated by it in particularly, it was more of a qualifier for what I was writing and, maybe, if a memento at all, only to those who are replying, myself to begin with...  Cheers.